# Web PHP instance will not run executable despite permissions being correct

Tags: php, linux, ssh

Perhaps you could help me with a rather frustrating problem.  I was unable to compile an executable, let's call it `$$execprob`, on the Linux host I'm doing testing on so compiled it on a different host and moved the executable over.  It runs fine with my SSH user but when the webserver uses

```
exec( "/home/$$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob", $output, $return );
```

I get no `$output` and `$return` is 127, or file not found.

Here is a list of information from my testing that may help:

- The file runs fine in normal SSH mode.
- The permissions through SSH are `-rwxr-xr-x`.
- Running `exec( 'ls -l' )` as the webserver shows that the file is there with the same permissions as SSH
- in SSH: `${USER}` is file owner $$username
- in PHP: `${USER}` returns nothing
- Running `exec( 'if [-x /home/$$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob]; then echo "thing";fi' )` prints out 'thing';
- In SSH running `php -a` and entering `exec( "/home/$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob", $output, $return );` runs $$execprob properly, with `$output` showing output and `$return` == 0.
- I have line in my .bashrc that loads the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` properly: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;`  This is necessary for the executable to run as it uses a dynamic library.  My .bashrc is not run by the webserver; however, running:

`exec( "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
        /home/$$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob", $output, $return );`

still has the same unsuccessful result.

If there's anything else I can do to gather more troubleshooting info for you please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: In your PHP script, try `print "/home/$$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob"` to make sure it's resolving any variable names properly etc.

Comment: Thanks, @JoelC, for thinking about the problem. I actually don't use any variable names at all.  I've just used these placeholders here to represent my username and the executable filename.  ie. I'm really just running ```/home/jonnybajonny/usr/local/bin/execfilename``` and that isn't working.

Comment: Can you make sure that others have rx permissions on all folders in the folder chain? If not, the PHP user won't be able to see the file to run it. Also check your webserver error logs to see if there's any PHP errors there.

Comment: Also, you can't use `$HOME` in your `export` statement like you have in the example as it will use the home directory of the user that the web server is executing under.

Comment: @JoelC: Yes, after replying to your comment above I realized that var might not resolve properly and made that a direct path and it worked!  Now I come back and that's exactly what you said.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally traced to the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable not being set properly.  I had this line:

```
exec( "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
    /home/$$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob", $output, $return );
```

However, of course, (as mentioned by @JoelC above,) the `$HOME` variable in the `export` command will resolve to the `$HOME` of the PHP user.  This was fixed by using the absolute path as such:

```
exec( "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/$$username/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
    /home/$$username/usr/local/bin/$$execprob", $output, $return );
```

It's worth noting that there was absolutely no output returned to help diagnosing this, which is strange.  When I run `$$execprob` from the shell without the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set it returns an error about the missing .so file.  Why wouldn't that same error be returned as the output here?  Perhaps there's a different category of output for system messages as opposed to actual command output?  I wonder if there is a way to have those types of messages be returned in the `exec()` scope.

But I suppose that's a question for another post...